# Rewrite Rule to redirect /dir or /dir/ to /dir/index.html where dir can be anything

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know apache has the default file to load when the request is a directory, but I want to have it redirect to the actual index.html file so my URL says /dir/index.html rather than /dir/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This three rules should do its job:

```
RewriteCond -d %{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond -f %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1/index.html [l]
```

The first line checks if the uri is a directory the second checks if there is inside a index.html and if so redirect the user to this file.

And for php files this two lines:

```
RewriteCond -d %{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond -f %{REQUEST_URI}/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1/index.php [l]
```